# Greasemonkey: Text processing - What's the best way to find certain words in a website and have a function work on it?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, greasemonkey

I want greasemonkey to scan through a website and change certain words to something else.  Is there a way to do it with regex or some other string processing function in javascript?

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In greasemonkey you use the DOM and then on the text nodes regular expressions might be used for finding your words. Check the [Wikiproxy](http://wikiproxy.whitelabel.org/greasemonkey.html) user script for an example that searches for words and changes stuff.